# Powershell Select-String : how to get fullPath and context lines

Tags: powershell

I have this working

```
select-string -path C:\test\*.txt -pattern "test" -allmatches –simplematch | foreach-object {
    Write-Host $_.Filename
    Write-Host $_.LineNumber
    Write-Host $_.Line
    Write-Host $_.context.postcontext
 }
```

But I'd like to also get FullPath instead of just FileName. I'd like to get also context lines before and after Line but can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filepath is available in the `Path`-property. To get the context you need first specify how many lines to capture before and after using `-Context 2` (2 lines before and after) or `-Context 1,2` (1 before, 2 after). Ex.

```
select-string -path C:\test\*.txt -pattern "test" -AllMatches -SimpleMatch -Context 1,1 | foreach-object {
    Write-Host
    Write-Host "MATCH!"
    Write-Host "-------------"
    Write-Host "Path $($_.Path)"
    Write-Host "Line number: $($_.LineNumber)"
    Write-Host "Before: $($_.Context.Precontext)"
    Write-Host "Line: $($_.Line)"
    Write-Host "After: $($_.Context.Postcontext)"
 }
```

Sample input (Text1.txt):

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line test
Line 4
Line 5
```

Sample output:

```
MATCH!
-------------
Path C:\test\Text2.txt
Line number: 4
Before: Line 3
Line: Line test
After: Line 5

MATCH!
-------------
Path C:\test\Text1.txt
Line number: 3
Before: Line 2
Line: Line test
After: Line 4
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Context` property doesn't get populated without using the `-Context` switch. The resulting object also has the `Path` property that has the full path info you're looking for.

Didn't take much to update it. Using your example:

```
select-string -path C:\test\*.txt -pattern "SG" -allmatches –simplematch -context 1 | foreach-object {
    Write-Host $_.Filename
    Write-Host $_.Path
    Write-Host $_.LineNumber
    Write-Host $_.Line
    Write-Host $_.context.postcontext
 }
```